# find folders and cd into them

Tags: bash, shell, find

I wanted to write a short script with the following structure:

```
 find the right folders
 cd into them
 replace an item
```

So my problem is that I get the right folders from `find`but I don't know how to do the action for every line `find`is giving me. I tried it with a for loop like this:

```
for item in $(find command)
  do magic for item
done
```

but the problem is that this command will print the relative pathnames, and if there is a space within my path it will split the path at this point.

I hope you understood my problem and can give me a hint.

Comment: `find . -name blah -exec do_stuff_to {} \;`

Comment: Look into `find -exec` and `xargs`

Answer (score 3):

You can run commands with -exec option of find directly:

```
find . -name some_name -exec your_command {} \;
```

Comment: the `pwd` was there because the question wanted to use absolute paths. If you use . it will return relative paths. So I think `pwd` was actually useful. What do you say?

Comment: if PATH contains path your `pwd` does not work. if you "really" need to use it you should quote with "`pwd`"

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is:

```
find command -print0 |
while IFS= read -r -d '' item ; do
    ... "$item" ...
done
```

`-print0` and `read ... -d ''` cause the NUL character to be used to separate paths, and ensure that the code works for all paths, including ones that contain spaces and newlines.  Setting `IFS` to empty and using the `-r` option to `read` prevents the paths from being modified by `read`.

Note that the `while` loop runs in a subshell, so variables set within it will not be visible after the loop completes.  If that is a problem, one way to solve it is to use process substitution instead of a pipe:

```
while IFS= ...
    ...
done < <(find command -print0)
```

Another option, if you have got Bash 4.2 or later, is to use the `lastpipe` option (`shopt -s lastpipe`) to cause the last command in pipelines to be run in the current shell.

Comment: This solution is working perfectly in my case. Thanks to all of you

Answer (score 0):

If the pattern you want to find is simple enough and you have bash 4 you may not need `find`. In that case, you could use `globstar` instead for recursive globbing:

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s globstar
for directory in **/*pattern*/; do
    (
    cd "$directory"
    do stuff
    )
done
```

The parentheses make each operation happen in a subshell. That may have performance cost, but usually doesn't, and means you don't have to remember to `cd` back each time.

If `globstar` isn't an option (because your `find` instructions are not a simple pattern, or because you don't have a shell that supports it) you can use `find` in a similar way:

```
find . -whatever -exec bash -c 'cd "$1" && do stuff' _ {} \;
```

You could use `+` instead of `;` to pass multiple arguments to bash each time, but doing one directory per shell (which is what `;` would do) has similar benefits and costs to using the subshell expression above.